How do I change background color of a toggle switch with javascript?
I was creating a library project, every book is a object with properties title, author, pages, and read-status stored in a array.
There's an 'add book' button which opens a modal and asks the user the title, author, pages of the book they want to add and there's a checkbox for 'read' status.
A checked checkbox returns a true value to the book object and an unchecked checkbox returns false.
In the interface the 'read' status is a toggle switch which the user can toggle to update his 'read' status of the book. I want to change the background color of that switch according to the user.
The bgColor is blue or red according to true and false values of 'read' status respectively. The user should also able to change the read status to true or false in the book object stored in the library by toggling the switch from the screen.
My book looks something like this in HTML:


.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #e20505;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.switch input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196f3;
  /* bgColor when check-box is checked */
}
<div class="single-books">
  <div id="title" class="card">
    <p class="keys" id="title-key">
      Title:
    </p>
    <p class="values" id="title-value">
      Men are from mars, women are from venus
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="author" class="card">
    <p class="keys" id="author-key">
      Author:
    </p>
    <p class="values" id="author-value">
      John Gray
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="pages" class="card">
    <p class="keys" id="pages-key">
      Pages:
    </p>
    <p class="values" id="pages-value">
      286
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="read-status" class="card">
    <p>Read status</p>
    <div class="toggle-switch">
      <div>No</div>
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id="change-read-status">
        <span class="slider"></span>
      </label>
      <div>Yes</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



library array will look like this:
library = [
  { title: "book1", author: "author1", pages: 100, read: true },
  { title: "book2", author: "author2", pages: 100, read: false },
];

I tried, getting the checkbox value from user if checkbox.checked === true and tried change the backGrounColor of the switch, and I am not able to understand how it can be done.
I saw other questions but I am not able to solve this. It's probably easy but my small brain can't understand.
edit: the site if it helps
https://muzzu153.github.io/library/

If you navigate to the page you have linked, the render acts as you have specified. The only bug I see is when you add a new book, the state of other records reset (which I'm assuming because you don't have persistent store connected in the demo).

Then do I need to make use of localStorage in someway,. I just looked it up, and it being something new I just saw, can't really understand how would I solve this using localStorage.

You can use any "storage" to accomplish this. You can use localStorage for it to last in the browser session, you can use fs in Node to write to a file, or make a POST call to your DB to persist the data.
